# Are acid anhydride and anhydride the same thing?

Tags: organic-chemistry

In my organic chemistry course, I have been made familiar with the term acid anhydride and anhydride.

I know that anhydride denotes the structure :

[image]

But I am confused about whether acid anhydride means the same thing.

Please provide some clarification on this.

Comment: This only acid anhydride.

Comment: The thing is, my instructors have repeatedly used the term 'anhydride'. So is it just a shorter way of saying 'acid anhydride'?

Comment: @AniruddhMukherjee if you are learning Organic Chemistry and especially about carboxylic acids, anhydrides would refer to acid anhydrides. It depends on the context.

Comment: An anhydride is anything that has a water removed from it, how would you remove water with two acid molecules of the form $\ce{R^1 -COOH}$ and $\ce{R^2 -COOH}$ respectively.

Comment: Acid anhydrides are of 2 types: Organic acid anhydride $\ce{R(CO)O(CO)R'}$ and inorganic acid anhydride which refers to [acidic oxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acidic_oxide).

Comment: I would point out that many compounds, that formally fit the general definition of an anhydride are not referred as anhydrides, or just seldom. The only anhydrides regularly referred so are anhydrides of organic acids. Carbon suboxide C3O2 is anhydride of malonic acid in general sense, aside of the narrow sense "true" malonic anhydride C3H2O3. Or, as a very extreme absurd example, carbon is an anhydride of "carbs", which has origin in the German term Kohlenhydrate = hydrate of carbon. Similarly, acid-forming oxides of nonmetals are seldom referred as anhydrides, unless this aspect is stressed.

Comment: @Poutnik This is what I understood, correct me if I am wrong: Acid anhydrides are obtained by the removal of water from carboxylic acids, and hence the 'acid' in 'acid anhydride', and they fall under the set of anhydrides which may or may not be obtained from the dehydration of acids. And, in organic chemistry, we use the terms 'acid anhydrides' and 'anhydrides' interchangeably for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: I would say so. But it is formal path. Real obtaining of anhydrides may used different reactions. Some acids may decarboxylate or otherwise deteriorate instead of forming anhydride. Neither you can get AlCl3 by heating AlCl3 . 6 H2O.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Defining the concept of anhydride**

An ”anhydride” is a chemical entity that has been obtained by dehydrating a substrate (containing water either as water of crystallization, or bonded with the substrate). Thus, all acid anhydrides are anhydrides, but not all anhydrides are acid anhydrides.

Here is a more professional definition, from the Merriam-Webster dictionary:

> Definition of anhydride
> : a compound derived from another (such as an acid) by removal of the elements of water

**A quite usual example from the field of inorganic chemistry**

For example, copper (II) sulfate pentahydrate is, well, the hydrated form of the copper-based salt. Water is present there as water of crystallization, the water molecule is embedded within the crystal structure. Let's see the differences between the hydrate crystal and the anhydrous form (that is, the *anhydride*)
[image: Copper (II) sulfate pentahydrate, next to its anhydrous form]

This inorgani salt is different from the acid anhydrides so commonly encountered in organic chemistry! However, anhydrous copper (II) sulfate is still an anhydride. And so are the acid anhydrides you have mentioned.